# Trying to redefine a mapped network drive in place

Tags: windows, command-line, network-shares

I'm trying to redefine an existing mapped network drive using hte Net Use command line.  I saw a question-answer for Win7 that suggested that I use:

```
Net Use [Drive] [New Mapping] -
```

thus:

```
Net Use S: \\UNC path
```

However I get a 'System Error 85 - The Local Device Name is in Use' error

Any ideas what I might so instead, that doesn't need  a registry edit?

Comment: System Error 85 is drive mapping already exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot create a network mapping if another mapping is established.

In order to create the new mapping, you first have to delete the old mapping.

You can do this by typing:

```
net use /d s:
```

Now that s: is no longer mapped, you can map it again.

```
net use s: \\hostname\share
```